# bash, find a file in a subdirectory based on its content

Tags: bash

I have a directory structure like this:

```
project1/config.ini
project2/config.ini
project3/config.ini
```

and so on. 
I want to find out the config.ini files that contain a specific string, say "database=a"

Comment: -1 The question doesn't show any research effort.

Comment: the "research effort", in this case, would be several unsuccessful attempts that would make the question less clear. i appreciate the cleaness of some questions, and in short time there already are 3 answers. this should be taken into account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use find command to recursively search all files for a string. For example:

```
find . -type f -name config.ini -exec grep -l "database=a" {} +
```

Comment: +1 I like this answer because it conforms cleanly to the POSIX spec without GNU extensions, but also without giving up performance or clarity. (I still woulda used `grep -F` though.) ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would use grep:

```
cd your_folder && grep -r "database=a" *
```

Comment: why do you need `cd` here?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grep`:

```
grep -r -l --include=config.ini database=a .
```

This makes a recursive search (`-r`) in `.` for `database=a` only in files with the name `config.ini` and only lists the matched files (`-l`).

Answer (score 1):

Another short variant:

```
grep 'database=a' ./**/config.ini
#                   ^^-recursively search for all `config.ini` files
```

Warning: works only if you don't have zilion config files - in other case you can get an `Argument list too long` error..

If you want only name of the file

```
grep -l 'database=a' ./**/config.ini
```

Comment: I think you'd have to enable `globstar` in bash for that to work, wouldn't you?

Answer (score 1):

Most easiest :

grep -ri "database=a" */config.ini